# Unable to install IBM WebSphere Application Server V8.5x Developer Tools for Mars from Eclipse Marketplace

Tags: eclipse, jar, timeout, eclipse-marketplace

When trying to install WDT on top of Eclipse for JEE developers today using the Eclipse Marketplace, we get:

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Unable to read repository at http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/websphere/wasdev/updates/wdt/mars_comp/repository/plugins/com.ibm.etools.webedit.xulrunner_1.0.0.v20170227_1658.jar.
Read timed out
Unable to read repository at http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/websphere/wasdev/updates/wdt/mars_comp/repository/plugins/com.ibm.websphere.v85.core_1.0.200.v20170227_1658.jar.
Read timed out
```

I tried setting timeout in eclipse.ini without success.

-Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.readTimeout=30000

Then i tried downloading the jar com.ibm.websphere.v85.core_1.0.200.v20170227_1658.jar from http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/websphere/wasdev/updates/wdt/mars_comp/repository/plugins/ and its stuck at 3.0/44.0 MB

Comment: I have the same problem with 

http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/websphere/wasdev/updates/wdt/oxygen_comp/repository/plugins/com.ibm.websphere.v85.core_1.0.200.v20170613_0418.jar